# How to increase width of easy ui tooltip

Tags: title, jquery-easyui

I want to display a tooltip on an image. The width of the tooltip is not enough to include all the contents of the tooltip. How to increase its width so that the tooltip contents can be fit into tooltip.

Images and Tooltip contents are generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" class="easyui-tooltip" data-options="
            content: $('<div></div>'),
            onShow: function(){
                $(this).tooltip('arrow').css('left', 20);
                $(this).tooltip('tip').css('left', $(this).offset().left);
            },
            onUpdate: function(cc){
                cc.panel({
                    width: 500,
                    height: 'auto',
                    border: false,
                    href: '_content.html'
                });
            }
```